# Automation Error when executing SQL Server Script in Excel VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, execute

I am opening an SQL Server Connection in EXCEL VBA and on the objMyCmd.Execute line when it is using the SQL script I am getting this error message:

"Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)') Automation error"

I have reviewed other SO posts that seem to reference an issue with the connection string itself, but I don't believe that is the issue as I am able to pull the first few variables listed when eliminating the rest of the SQL script.

I have attempted to review the SQL code to see if I am using an incorrect format, or if the language is not written properly and I am not able to determine the issue. I am hoping with some Q & A we may notice something I have missed in how this is written? Please let me know if there is additional information I can provide, below is the code up to the point of error.

```
Sub SQL_GetAgentChart()
Dim dtDate As Date
Dim myTable As ListObject

Dim DataServer As String
Dim Database As String
Dim constring As String

DataServer = "GLSSQLMADP2"
Database = "PERF_MGMT_BWRSRV_PROD"
constring = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & DataServer & "; Database=" & Database & "; Trusted_Connection=yes"

Dim AVStartDate As Date
Dim AVEndDate As Date
Dim RepID As Long

'Declare variables'
Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
Set myTable = Worksheets("Witness").ListObjects("tblWitness")

AVStartDate = DateValue("Mar 01, 2016")
AVEndDate = DateValue("Mar 31, 2016")
RepID = 2040

'Open Connection'
objMyConn.ConnectionString = constring
objMyConn.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
objMyCmd.CommandText = " " & _
"SELECT PERSN_XTRNL_ID_NR, SOURCE, LOGGINGTS, DD7, CUREREASON, CUREDATE, LNSTATUS " & _
"FROM TTB " & _
"WITH INCALL AS (SELECT T.CUREREASON, CUREVALUE " & _
"FROM TTB T " & _
"JOIN PERSONNEL P ON T.PERSONNELID = P.PERSONNELID " & _
"LEFT JOIN CURETRANSLATE C ON T.CUREREASON = C.CUREREASON AND T.LNSTATUS = C.STATUS " & _
"WHERE T.PERSONNELID = " & RepID & " " & _
"AND LOGGINGTS > '" & AVStartDate & "' " & _
"AND LOGGINGTS < '" & AVEndDate + 1 & "' " & _
"AND INCOMING = 1 " & _
"AND DD7 > 0), OUTCALL AS (SELECT T.CUREREASON, CUREVALUE " & _
"FROM TTB T " & _
"JOIN AVAYA A ON T.UID = A.TTBUID " & _
"LEFT JOIN CURETRANSLATE C ON T.CUREREASON = C.CUREREASON AND T.LNSTATUS = C.STATUS " & _
"WHERE PERSONNELID = " & RepID & " " & _
"AND LOGGINGTS > '" & AVStartDate & "' " & _
"AND LOGGINGTS < '" & AVEndDate + 1 & "' " & _
"AND INCOMING = 0 " & _
"AND A.AVAYAGROUP IN ('15', '1A', '1B', '1C', '1D', '1E', '1F', '1G', '1H') " & _
"AND DD7 > 0) "

    objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    objMyCmd.Execute
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on 'objMyCmd.Execute'. Do a 'Debug.Print' of 'objMyCmd.CommandText'. Copy that statement and execute it against the db server directly; see if it executes as expected.